# resp.setBufferSize(2048); java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed or content written

Tags: java, servlets

I hava a problem in this code line:

```
resp.setBufferSize(2048);
```

catch this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed or content written
```

resp is HttpServletResponse

I have read about this but I don´t found the solution

Comment: You've already written data to the response object.

Comment: I don´t think so, before a only use resp.setContentType and resp.setHeader

Comment: post full method code for better help, it may be that exception is on this line but cause is some prior code

Comment: I think so, because the exception says so. If you want to debate it, post some code.

Comment: It is problem the timeout, the doGet method has a lot of code inside

Answer (score 0):

We can't really tell you how to solve this without seeing your actual code.

But it is absolutely clear that you are calling the setBufferSize method too late.  Something that your application has done to the response object prior to that call has "committed" the response.